# Visual Studio 2013 : no symbols loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

What is happening here? Everything was working fine, but now when I try to load a page with data from SQL Server, this appears in VS:

[image]

Comment: Use the debugger to see what exception was thrown.

Comment: @SLaks An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Comment: Look at the call stack to see what is happening.

Comment: This is on top of the call stack   "EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.Node n) Unknown"

Comment: Look in the middle of the call stack.  You either have a vastly-too-complex query or infinite recursion in your own code.

Comment: What am I looking for exactly? I think my code is very basic, would it be a infinite recursive code in sqlserver?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186939/discussion-between-conor8630-and-slaks).

Comment: It would be easier to help if we could see the call stack.

Comment: @Amy its very large though! I think I may have uninstalled some important files though. I'm now being prompted with a "find source: list.cs". I could show you the callstack on teamviewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. I guess I was creating an infinite loop of code from a foreign key on the same table in the database. I just removed the foreign key and everything works fine.